# Asp.Net Mvc3 Jquery validate manually showing error messages

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I have the following input:

```
<input class="text-box single-line hasDatepicker valid" id="RiskInputModel_Filters_StartDate" name="RiskInputModel.Filters.StartDate" type="text" value="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"><br>
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="RiskInputModel.Filters.StartDate.Value"  data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

and after a bit of ajaxy goodness I want to do the following:

```
var validator = $("form").validate();

var obj = { };
obj[responseText.message.fieldName] = responseText.message.errorText;
validator.showErrors(obj);
```

where responseText.message.fieldName is `RiskInputModel.Filters.StartDate`

I have tried with `RiskInputModel_Filters_StartDate`

but neither actually does anything?

as well as appening .Value or _Value to the end respectively

am i missing something obvious here?

UPDATE

if i run this in the console:

```
$('form').validate().showErrors({"RiskInputModel.Filters.StartDate" : "Start date must be less than or equal to End date."});
```

it doesn't error - so must be finding the element to validate with - but does nothing with it?

Answer (score 0):

Your validation span appears to have the wrong data-valmsg-for; you need to remove the .Value.  `data-valmsg-for` needs to match the `name` of the input.

It should be:

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="RiskInputModel.Filters.StartDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```